# US Lenovo Thinkpad Tablet in India - mobile data

Tags: internet, lenovo-thinkpad-tablet

I bought Lenovo Thinkpad Tablet 32GB from US andI am now in India. I have a vodafone 2G SIM. How can I connect this to my Thinkpad?

And I have a M blaze data card. Can this be connected to the thinkpad ?

Answer (score 1):

If the SIM card doesn't work out of the box in your TPT, it's very likely that your US tablet is not compatible with the mobile communication standards used in India. What happens if you put the SIM in the TPT?

Mobile data USB sticks can't be used with the TPT, afaik.

Answer (score 1):

You may need to manually specify the network and/or APNs in `Settings->Wireless and network->Mobile networks->Access Point Names` - vodafone's tech support for vodafone should be able to provide these for you.  I have to do this when I use my WIND Mobile SIM card in Canada on my phone.